# failsafe+testng run tests that are not explicitly marked with the group name when I request to only run the group

Tags: maven, testng, maven-failsafe-plugin

I marked only 1 test class with "http-integration-test" group:

```
@Test(groups = "http-integration-test", timeOut = 60_000)
public class MyIT
```

and then ran "mvn clean integration-test". I see multiple tests are run, not just those from this particular class.

why does failsafe maven plugin + testng combination ignore the request to only run "http-integration-test" group?

my pom.xml :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-ea -Xmx256m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <groups>http-integration-test</groups>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                            <include>**/IT*.java</include>
                            <include>**/TestServerConfigurator.java</include>
                            <include>*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

and here's the parent pom file section:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <!-- the default configuration of surefire executes unit
                    tests implemented using JUnit. please see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html
                    for details on these options -->
                <configuration>
                    <!-- -XX:UseSplitVerifier: use legacy class verification; required until javassist can be updated to >= 3.18.2-GA -->
                    <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
                    <!-- disable execution of TestNG in case there are both
                        JUnit and TestNG tests available for execution -->
                    <testNGArtifactName>none:none</testNGArtifactName>
                    <excludes>
                        <!-- Integration Tests end in *IntegrationTest, by
                             convention -->
                        <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*IntegrationTestSuite.class</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <includes>
                        <!-- Unit Tests should end in *Test, by convention -->
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <!-- Include *TestCase, because there are a large
                            number of tests named this way -->
                        <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: If you run `mvn clean integration-test` the life cycle will run which means that unit tests will run as well..Furthermore why are you redefining the defaults for includes/excludes of maven-surefire/maven-failsafe. Best is to follow the naming conventions and name unit tests like `*Test.java` and integration tests like `*IT.java` (details in the docs)

Comment: You "see multiple tests are run, not just those from this particular class." Can you provide the names of the tests that run and along with which phase of the build lifecycle they run in (i.e. `test` or `integration-test`)?

Comment: khmarbaise - the goal of having two separate plugins (surefire and failsafe) is to split unit and integration tests. "test" phase will be executed, but it should not include tests matching **/*IntegrationTest. I expect Maven to run only unit tests (by surefire) and then failsafe should only run tests matching "**/*IntegrationTest" and "**/*IT" which are marked by "groups" tag. I will update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Alex did you get around solving this for you? If yes, it would be great to answer your own question. I am facing the same issue.